# Fastest Dynamic Webserver Build for 2011?

Tags: web-server, performance, vps

I am wondering what your favorite build is for a new dynamic website (of unknown traffic especially)?

After scouring the web, it seems that Apache with an Ngnix reverse proxy does not offer any benefits with unless you need Apache for cPanel, or are more comfortable with it (i'm not, just starting out).

***My current config in mind*** 
*Linode 512mb VPS, can scale up as needed.
 
Ubuntu 10.04 (most comfortable with that)
 
Latest Nginx
 
PHP5-FPM
 
X-Cache or APC*

I would love to hear what your build would be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a vague question. One of the biggest determining factor contributing to the performance of the website is the quality of the code that is being run on the infrastructure.

Infrastructure works as fast as the slowest link, which most of the time is application code or Database.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering what your favorite build is for a new dynamic website (of unknown traffic 
>   especially)?

None. Put it on a shared server. Itf it NEES dedicated server for some reasons...

- 512mb minimum ramwith windows, maximum 8gb, 2 cores. Then watch how it behaves and wait for SCOM to tell me it is not good enough. Reconfigure as needed.

;) Obviously that is the approach because I have about 96gb memory and 20 processor cores in my own little private personal cloud, so I can assign ressources as needed.